# What's the name Hakumen no Mono wanted to be called as?

Tags: ushio-to-tora

In the anime climax, Hakumen no Mono vaporizes, saying

> My name is not Hakumen.
>   The name I wanted to be called is...

What was that name? I don't see any reference anywhere on what that name was.

Comment: "Hakumen no Mono" is a title/epithet, meaning "the white-faced one". My inference is that Hakumen had an actual personal name (which is never revealed) by which it wanted to be called.

Comment: so theres no name? is there any reference to hokumen no mono in japanese myth, which the anime the took upon?

Answer (score 2):

My theory about its "real name" is, either Towako, the name of hakumen's avatar, maybe Hakumen named its avatar the real name for self-satisfaction? and the second probable name, is kirio/Inasa, as in Kirio Inasa, the boy whom it kidnapped. after the kidnapping, it probably change his name as it likes.

I personally think, Towako is the "Real name".

Comment: Thanks, but am not familiar with Japanese, can you provide the meaning behind the names?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion i think Hakumen’s real name might have something to do with the baby shown as he vaporizes and yin/yang because in the end he does not fall as negative ki which creates other youkai, but he floats upwards as positive ki. Maybe in the end he died a peaceful death and he could now be reborn as a human, not a mass of hate.We can also assume he would have a woman name since his voice when he whispers “The name i was called was...” is a feminine one.